# How to plot a vertical histogram with a central value other than zero with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using the following code to plot some data:

```
self.arms = df['arms'].iloc[-self.plotlength:]
self.armsup = [0 if i < 1.0 else log(i, 10) for i in self.arms]
self.armsdn = [0 if i > 1.0 else log(i, 10) for i in self.arms]

a1.plot(self.x, self.openarms - 1, color='k')
a1.vlines(self.x, 0, self.armsup, color='g')
a1.vlines(self.x, 0, self.armsdn, color='r')
```

With the following result (lower chart clip)
[image]

The histogram is currently centered on zero. It really should be centered on one. Currently I am adjusting the data by subtracting one. How can I plot vertical lines that swing above and below some arbitrary number like one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are taking the log of every value in `self.arms` and that you know the median value should be around 1.0. So instead of

```
self.arms = df['arms'].iloc[-self.plotlength:]
self.armsup = [0 if i < 1.0 else log(i, 10) for i in self.arms]
self.armsdn = [0 if i > 1.0 else log(i, 10) for i in self.arms]
```

you could use

```
self.arms = df['arms'].iloc[-self.plotlength:]
self.armsup = [1.0 if log(i, 10) < 1.0 else log(i, 10) for i in self.arms]
self.armsdn = [1.0 if log(i, 10) > 1.0 else log(i, 10) for i in self.arms]
```

or, similarly, using NumPy:

```
self.arms = df['arms'].iloc[-self.plotlength:]
log_arms = np.log(self.arms)
threshold = 1
mask = log_arms > threshold
armsup = np.where(mask, log_arms, threshold)
armsdn = np.where(~mask, log_arms, threshold)
```

[`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) has call signature `np.where(cond, x, y)` where `cond` is a boolean array, `x` and `y` are arrays of the same length as `cond`, and `np.where(cond, x, y)` returns values from `x` where `cond` is True and from `y` where `cond` is False.

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 100
arms = np.random.uniform(0.5, 4.0, N)
log_arms = np.log(arms)
threshold = 1
mask = log_arms > threshold
armsup = np.where(mask, log_arms, threshold)
armsdn = np.where(~mask, log_arms, threshold)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.arange(N)
ax.vlines(x, threshold, armsup, color='g')
ax.vlines(x, armsdn, threshold, color='r')
plt.show()
```

yields
[image]

Comment: That was the first thing I tried. Here is the result with the data in its original base one form. https://imgur.com/a/ltBGN What I'd like is bars rising and falling from one.

Comment: The data ranges from 0.5 to 4.0 or so, with one being neutral. So the desired result is green bars above one and red bars descending from one.

Comment: Check your values for `armsup` and `armsdn`. Notice that in the original graph, the maximum `armsup` value is about 0.5. Compare that with [other graph](https://imgur.com/a/ltBGN) which has a maximum `armsup` value of over 3. There is no way adding 1 to `armsup` should produce the second graph. So I don't know where your mistake is, but it is not in the code you (or I) posted.

Comment: Sorry, I used logs of the data to get it normalized around zero. I'll add that above.

Comment: Does `self.arms` range from 0.5 to 4.0?